# Rounding time to nearest hourly quarter in postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I have timestamp column as:

```
"2017-02-14 05:06:34"
"2017-01-17 13:55:44"
"2017-01-17 14:06:14"
"2017-01-17 22:40:14"
"2017-01-18 14:23:43"
```

and I want to round time to nearest hourly quarter in postgresql. I want to update as 1,2,3,4 quaters

The output I need is as follows:

```
"2017-02-14 05:06:34"  1
"2017-01-17 13:55:44"  4
"2017-01-17 14:06:14"  1
"2017-01-17 22:40:14"  3
"2017-01-18 14:23:43"  2
```

I tried the following command but it is not giving me as expected:

```
SELECT   CURRENT_TIME(0), 
CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIME(0)) - 30   >= 0 
                    THEN CURRENT_TIME(0) + ((60 - EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIME(0))) * INTERVAL  '1' MINUTE)
               ELSE CURRENT_TIME(0) -  EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIME(0))  * INTERVAL  '1' MINUTE
END  AS Converted_Time from table1;
```

CURRENT_TIME is the column in my table.

Comment: Why did `2017-01-17 22:45:14` change to `2017-01-17 22:40:14` and `2017-01-18 14:11:43` to `2017-01-18 14:23:43` in the expected output? And why are you using `current_Time` in your query and not the column name of your table?

Answer (score 1):

A few years later I came here to find how to round a timestamp to a 6 hour interval.

Here is my solution adapted to the question given:

```sql
SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC('minute', NOW())
    -
    MAKE_INTERVAL(MINS => MOD(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM NOW())::INTEGER, 15))
```

Explanation:

1. `DATE_TRUNC` the timestamp to the minutes
2. `EXTRACT` the `MINUTE` from the timestamp
3. Convert the minute to an `INTEGER`
4. Get the remainder of dividing the minute by 15 (`MOD`)
5. Convert the result to an interval (`MAKE_INTERVAL`)
6. Subtract that from the truncated timestamp from 1.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following conditions for each of the quarters:

1. `MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIME(0)) - 15  <= 0` 
2. 0 < `MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIME(0)) - 15  <= 15` 
3. 15 < `MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIME(0)) - 15  <= 30` 
4. 30 < `MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIME(0)) - 15  <= 45`

Comment: I am getting the error for the 3 conditions only first condition is working.             ERROR:  syntax error at or near "0"
LINE 4: WHEN EXTRACT(0 < MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIME(0)) - 15  <= ...
                     ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "0"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 119

Comment: I am using the following query: SELECT   CURRENT_TIME(0), 
(CASE 
WHEN EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIME(0)) - 15   <= 0 then 1
WHEN EXTRACT(0 < MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIME(0)) - 15  <= 15 then 2
WHEN EXTRACT(15 < MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIME(0)) - 15  <= 30 then 3 
WHEN EXTRACT(30 < MINUTE FROM CURRENT_TIME(0)) - 15  <= 45  <= 15 then 4
END) from table t1;